# How does JVM PC counter and stack space work with JIT?

Tags: java, jvm, jit

When a Java method get JIT-compiled and start running the JIT-ed native code:

1. Is the stack space still the same with previous one which running in interpreter mode?
2. Does the PC counter still being updated when running in JIT mode? if so, how?

(Let's say we are using OpenJDK).

Answer (score 0):

> Is the stack space still the same with previous one which running in interpreter mode?

The call stack is the same. It doesn't rebuild the stack when JIT-ed code is swapped in.

The value stack however can be assigned to registers and thus not maintained in native code.

> Does the PC counter still being updated when running in JIT mode? if so, how?

The CPU's PC counter is used in native mode. The virtual registers are notional in native optimised code.

Comment: Did you mean 'The virtual registers' is JVM 's 'Program Counter (PC) Register' ? and what does 'notional' mean? if the JIT-ed code de-optimized to interpreter mode, does the JVM 's 'Program Counter (PC) Register'  need to be updated?

Comment: @Anonemous The PC counter is need for interpreted code but isn't maintained AFAIK when running native code. The call stack is maintained but the evaluation stack can be assigned to registers at runtime.